Altium Polygon clearance in Room
In altium i have two polygon which flows inside a room and also outside that room. I have defined in room clearence between 2 polygon is 15 mils and outside the room is 40 mils. But the clearence is taking 40 mils even inside the room?

Can you please show a screenshot of how you have your rules set up?

This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

@ChrisKnudsen No it won't..

https://forum.live.altium.com seems to be working as of 2024/04/22.  Perhaps it was down when you last tried?  What did you get/see when you attempted to access it?  I am not affiliated with Altium in any way.  However, EESE does tend to get flooded with Altium questions every so often, and many seem to be not aware of the best resource for such questions.
